# "Compilation failed in require at /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/App/DuckPAN/Cmd.pm line 22."

Tags: perl, duckduckgo-api

I can't seem to get duckpan to work. Here is the error I am receiving, any ideas?

```
Checking for latest App::DuckPAN ... 0.135
Checking for latest DDG Perl package... 0.120
```

Using the following DDG instant answers:

```
 - DDG::Goodie::ABC (Words)
 - DDG::Goodie::AltCalendars (Words)
 - DDG::Goodie::Anagram (Words)
 - DDG::Goodie::Ascii (Words)
 - DDG::Goodie::AspectRatio (Words)
 - DDG::Goodie::Atbash (Words)
 - DDG::Goodie::Average (Words)
Can't locate Math/Int2Base.pm in @INC (@INC contains: lib /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at lib/DDG/Goodie/Base.pm line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/DDG/Goodie/Base.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at /home/ubuntu/perl5/lib/perl5/App/DuckPAN/Cmd.pm line 22.
```

Comment: Not familiar with the specifics of this situation, but the error message indicates something is trying (and failing) to use a package called `Math::Int2Base`. [CPAN does have a package by that name](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Int2Base), so the naive solution is to install it and try again (ie: `cpanm Math::Int2Base` or `perl -MCPAN -e 'install Math::Int2Base'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rutter mentioned, the problem is that you're missing a dependency for the Goodie package.

DuckPAN provides an easy way to install all the dependencies (which installed them via CPAN as rutter suggested), once you're in the root of your Goodie repo (zerclickinfo-goodie), run `duckpan installdeps` and this will install everything necessary to run `duckpan server` or `duckpan query`.

BTW, in the future it's best to report these issues in the relevant repo, in this case the DuckPAN repo: https://github.com/duckduckgo/p5-app-duckpan, as we check those daily.